# mail-listener2 - How to prevent function from reading wrong emails?

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor, imap

In my E2E test, I'am using the [mail-listener2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener2) to retrieve e-mails. It works fine, except one issue which is driving me crazy and just can't solve it... I have been searching and found different topics and issues regarding this library/package, but just couldn't really find the fix for that.

Following:

I use the function in more than one `spec` file (register, login, confirmation etc.), and this means that when retrieving the emails, I get from time to time the wrong one. In other words, the function reads the last e-mail in the Inbox which normally belongs to the first test.

Or sometimes the e-mail comes in the Inbox a little bit later that the function is reading them, so it reads the wrong one.

And as I do have an expectation in my `it()` function:

**`expect(email.subject).toEqual("subject for e-mail 1");
 expect(email['headers'].to).toEqual( userEmail );`**

therefore the test breaks, and it get following error:

```
  - Expected 'user registration' to equal 'user confirmation'.
  - Failed: Cannot read property '1' of null

  - Expected 'john.doe@foo.de' to equal 'jane.doe@foo.com'.
  - Failed: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

Is there a way how to force the function reads just the specific email per subject and per user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can find this documented on [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) (which is used by `mail-listener2`).  Search for the paragraph/bullet on `search` within that package, here's a snippet to help you find it:

> For criteria types that require arguments, use an array instead of just the string criteria type name (e.g. ['FROM', 'foo@bar.com']).

Below that, they list several other search criteria you can use, they have `to/from` for your user criteria, and `subject` for that one.  So applying this to `mail-listener2`, you would use this in the `searchFilter` property:

```
mailListener = new MailListener({
    ...(other options),
    searchFilter: [['FROM', 'automated@message.com'], ['SUBJECT', 'subject for e-mail 1']],
});
```

And if you need different search criteria for different tests, you can start a new `mail-listener` session for each test with the new `searchFilter` criteria.

Comment: Yes, you're right... I have been reading this documentation, but in my test I'am checking `email['headers'].to` as when I retrieve the email, I check if it's the correct user who's receiving the e-mail. And also the subject is different from Email to other one, cause the processes I'am testing are different. Once the subject is: `register` and  once the subject is: `confirmation` and third time is `DOI confirmation`. I have to use in a way a dynamic variable which reads the recipient e-mail and e-mail-subject. I have updated my Question...

Comment: Sorry I'm not following, whats wrong with the solution?  Your question was "force the function reads just the specific email per subject and per user".  I have provided a solution that limits the email by `subject` and either `to` a specific user or `from` a specific user.

Comment: That's great... I didn't mean it's wrong, but it's just I can't define a final subject as the subject differ from e-mail and test to the other. But I'll give it a try and see how it works.

Comment: You can just start a new `mail-listener` session for each test so they can search by their own criteria

Comment: Exactly.. this is what I was going to try. Great!

Comment: I think you saved my day! I did run at least 30 tests and al of them were successful! I'am starting the mail-Listener session per test `it()` where I do need to retrieve the email - Great Support/Job!

Comment: Sure! Would you please add also your last comment to you answer... you last hin was really helpful!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166514/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-gunderson).